# Jackson : Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_TRUE token

Tags: android, json, jackson

I'm getting this error when deserialzing json to an ArrayList

```
12-31 05:29:10.963: W/System.err(2939): org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_TRUE token
```

here's the structure of the json:

```
{
"c_Evenement" : [{
        "id" : {
            "o_id" : 9,
            "t_id" : 1,
            "key" : "1_9"
        },
        "bla1" : "bla bla bla bla",
        "bla2" : "bla bla bla bla",
        "bla3" : "bla bla bla bla",
        "bla4" : "bla bla bla bla"
    }
],
"themes" : [{
        "id" : 1,
        "nom" : "Administration"
    }
    ],
"c_Theme" : [{
        "id" : {
            "couche_id" : 761,
            "theme_id" : 1,
            "key" : "1_761"
        },
        "layerId" : 0
    }
],
"message" : null,
"ok" : true
}
```

here's the LireTheme class :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class LireTheme {

private Themes themes;
private CouchesTheme c_Theme;
private ClassesEvenement c_Evenement;

private String message;
private boolean ok;

//getters and setters

}
```

here's the LireTheme class that is simply a mapping HashMap :

```
public class LireThemes extends HashMap<String, ArrayList<LireTheme>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

and here's how i deserialize it :

```
LireThemes lirethemes = null;
ArrayList<LireTheme> themeList = null;
final InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("lireThemes.json");
lirethemes = objectMapper.readValue(stream, LireThemes.class);
themeList = lirethemes.get("themes");
```

i really need help please.

Comment: I think the issue JacksonMapper is having is that it doesn't know how to deserialize the attributes c_Evenement and c_Theme, because in the class they contain different names. Try using always the same name, is that possible?

Comment: the properties and classes have the same names in json. it's only the LireTheme class who doesn't have an attribute in json and i put     @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) to ignore it

Comment: Now the json it's not valid, maybe while updating something went wrong :/

Parse error on line 19:
...istration"        }"c_Theme": [       
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

Comment: sorry facundofarias i just forget "]," before "c_Theme" but this is not the real json i've just created this one to show the architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, so now I can see that each one of those attributes are collections, not simple attributes. So for each one of those, Jackson it's trying to map to a List, for example.
So, try with:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class LireTheme {

private List<Themes> themes;
private List<CouchesTheme> c_Theme;
private List<ClassesEvenement> c_Evenement;

private String message;
private boolean ok;

//getters and setters

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually you showed me another error :-) but thank you this helps me alot